# Run netcat in background on Ubuntu Lucid 10.04

Tags: linux, postgresql, netcat, background-process, nohup

I am trying to do a pg_dump from one server and simultaneously restore at the other server.

The command on source server  (192.168.3.94):

```
pg_dumpall -v  | nc 192.168.3.95  4000
```

The command on the target server (192.168.3.95):

```
nc -l 4000 | psql mydb
```

Now I am running this from my PC via Putty. Since this process take ~5 hours, I want to background the jobs and close the terminal windows. But I am not able to figure out how to background both commands and also exit the shell.

Help!

Comment: See: [Using NetCat (nc) running in the background](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2010/03/using-netcat-nc-running-in-background.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use screen. If you run each end in a screen session, you can detach it (Ctrl-d) and log out while leaving it running.

Answer (score 1):

To start a process that is both backgrounded and detached form the running shell, you can do the following (using your example):

```
(pg_dumpall -v  | nc 192.168.3.95  4000 &)
```

`pstree` comes in handy here, for verifying that it's detached (or `ps -ejH` if you don't have it)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include '-d' on your listening daemon, I've run into problems with netcat, even in listen mode, not forking because it expects stdin.